# Why do I get a ConcurentModificationException when removing from a HashMap?

Tags: java, collections

I want to remove an item from HashMap, by applying a criteria. Consider this code:

```
Set<Foo> set = myMap.keySet();
Iterator<Foo> itr = set.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    Foo foo = itr.next();
    if (foo.toString().length() < 3) {
        myMap.remove(foo); //remove the pair if key length is less than 3
    }
}
```

So I get a ConcurentModificationException because during the iteration I am modifying the HashMap. What should I do? Is there any other way to search for my criteria and execute the remove command at the end so that I can avoid this exception?

Comment: If i use try/catch block, at run time the program is stuck somewhere and cursor keeps blinks. I have to terminate the program by CTR+C
Is there anyway i can do to avoid this situation and still be able to remove the key/value pair from HashMap

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `itr.remove()` instead of `myMap.remove(o.toString())`

Comment: Are you sure this works? The iterator in the question is not an iterator of the HashMap, but of the HashMap's key set.

Comment: Indeed you can use the `remove()` method on the keySet iterator to remove the key-value mapping: see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Removing the key will remove the whole entry

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - I believe that you are saying that `o.toString()` is wrong.  Correct?  You are right, but this is not the cause of the OP's immediate problem.

Answer (score 4):

As of Java 8, Collection provides [`removeIf(Predicate<? super E>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), which will remove all elements for which the given predicate returns true.  The example in the question could be rewritten as

```
myMap.keySet().removeIf(o -> o.toString().length() < 3);
```

The default implementation provided by Collection uses an iterator and calls `Iterator.remove`, but collections can override this if they can provide better implementations.  More importantly, code using `removeIf` is clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 3):

If you are removing element during iteration you have to use Iterator.remove() instead. Otherwise the current Iterator object enters inconsistent state  that causes the exception. You can use Map.remove(key) when you know key, i.e. when you are not iterating over the same Map.

This rule is correct for all collections (Lists, Sets etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - [`itr.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next.

The `Iterator` of the `keySet()` extends the `HashIterator`, whose `remove()` method calls `HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(key);`

You can also obtain the `entrySet()` if you need both the key and the value - its iterator has the same property.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you describe I personally like to use functional style programming:

```
Map<String,Object> map = // obtained somehow;

Map<String,Object> filtered = Maps.filterKeys(map, new Predicate() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.length() < 3;
    }
});
```

The code snippet uses the google collections library. It creates a view of the original map by taking only those entries which keys match the supplied predicate.